# Determine all graphs that contain $P_4$ but not $P_5$.

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

Let $P_n$ be a path with $n$ vertices. My question is as the title says: Determine all graphs that contain $P_4$ but not $P_5$.

The question is derived from the first exercise on page 115 of a book titled "Distances in Graphs" by Buckley and Harary, published in 1990.

I don't have any concrete ideas at the moment. The only thing I can come up with is that the diameters of these graphs are at most 3. However, there seem to be many graphs falling into this category.

The original text's "contain," I speculate, refers to including subgraphs rather than induced subgraphs. If changed to "contain induced subgraphs" as  Mathieu Rundström and user14111 suggested, I think this question also intriguing. However, I cannot estimate the difficulty level.

Comment: Start with the $P_4$ like the 'spine', and add edges and build around it.

Comment: @AaaLol_dude Thank you very much. I mistakenly equated it with graphs having a diameter less than or equal to 3. A graph may have a small diameter but still have long paths. The conditions here are much stricter.

Comment: Do you mean subgraph containment?

Comment: Does "contain" mean "contain as a subgraph" or "contain as an induced subgraph"? Is $K_4$ an example of a graph that contains $P_4$ but does not contain $P_5$?

Comment: @MathieuRundström The original text does not explicitly state, but I speculate it might refer to subgraphs. If the subgraphs here are induced, I think it would also be an interesting question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that connected graphs with this property can be given by three parameters $m\geq n>k\geq0$.

Let $u,u_1,\ldots,u_m,v,v_1,\ldots,v_n$ be pairwise different.
Let $S_m(u)=\{u,u_1,\ldots,u_m\}$ and $S_n(v)=\{v,v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ be stars with centres at $u$ and $v$, respectively. Let $G=S_m(u)\cup S_n(v)$ be supplemented with edges $uv$, $u_iv_i$, $i=1,\ldots,k$. The graph $G$ contains $P_4$ and does not contain $P_5$. The converse is also true.